# Android table: ImageView and TextView with no visible long text

Tags: android, text, textview, long-integer

I have TableLayout with two columns. If the text in TextView is longer than the screen size with a little bit - 6 or 7 symbols, this 6 or 7 symbols are not visible. If the text is longer with more symbols they are visible. It is a part of ListView and I load the text content and image in ImageView dynamically. I want the text in TextView always to be visible regardless of how long is it. What can I do?

Here is my layout xml content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_table_layout" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >
<TableRow>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_image" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Technical Support Representative"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my text:

```
    String messageTitleText = "<b> Xxxxxxx xxx xxx xx<br/> Xxxxxxxxxx<br/> Xxxxxxxxxxx<br/> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/> xxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx xx 1234567890<br/> xxxxxxx xxxx<br/> xxxxxxx xxxx xxxx";
    messageTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(messageTitleText));
```

My HTC don't show chars after "1234", "567890" are hidden.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:lines="4"
    android:text="Technical Support Representative"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't take effect. The text in TextView is multilines and only change visible lines number.

Comment: try adding more text in `android:text="Technical Support Representative"` you will see the result, like `android:text="Technical Support Representative, Technical Support Representative, Technical Support Representative, Technical Support Representative, Technical Support Representative...."`

Comment: Added in post my test text. Did you see it?

Comment: well it worked for me. check this link i have pasted my device [screenshot.](https://dyp.im/RLlo761IHf)

Comment: Try to set android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" to ImageView and you will see the problem. You didn't set src in ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this, and It's ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="120px"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```